# Laravel: Sometimes rule not working on input type=file

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, laravel-5, form-data

I'm creating a FormRequest that validates if it contains image depending on its field name. Below is what my rules looks like:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'username'              => 'required|exists:users',
        'key'                   => 'required|exists:users,activation_key',
        'id'                    => 'sometimes|required|array|min:2',
        'id.*'                  => 'sometimes|required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:5000',
        'documents'             => 'sometimes|required|array|min:4',
        'documents.*'           => 'sometimes|required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,doc,pdf,docx,zip|max:5000',
        'g-recaptcha-response'  => 'required',
    ];
}
```

On other terms, the array of uploaded files are validated when they are set. I'm handling this trough blade.

My request is done trough `Jquery.ajax()` and using `new FormData($('selector')[0])` to get the field values. I have my ajax params right so thats out of the factor.

The problem is, when making the HTTP request, with a blank form, the only thing that are being validated are `username`, `key`, and `g-recaptcha-response`

Further debugging shows that removing the `sometimes` rule makes it work. But I need to only conditionally check for one(e.g `/upload-id` will only show `id[]` fields and `/upload-documents`  will only show `document[]` fields).

Comment: Remove `sometimes|required` and use only `sometimes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is laravel somewhat ignores empty `input[type=file]` arrays and doesn't add it into the parameter bag in the `Request` Class. The workaround that i did was by using the `required_if` rules on the array items validation like so:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'username'              => 'required|exists:users',
        'key'                   => 'required|exists:users,activation_key',
        'account_type'          => ['required', Rule::in(['individual', 'business'])],
        'id'                    => 'nullable|array|min:2',
        'id.*'                  => 'required_if:account_type,individual|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:5000',
        'documents'             => 'nullable|array|min:4',
        'documents.*'           => 'required_if:account_type,business|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,doc,pdf,docx,zip|max:5000',
        'g-recaptcha-response'  => 'required'
    ];
}
```

here, i have a determinant on to which between the two will be validated, so if `account_type = individal`, it will only the validate deeper in the `id` array